# C# returning &quot; rather than "

Tags: asp.net

My code is returning `&quot;` rather than `"`

In .cs

```
public string openingVal
{
    get
    {
        string opening = "";
        opening += "\"openingHoursSpecification\": [";
        opening += "{";
        opening += "\"@type\": \"OpeningHoursSpecification\",";
        opening += "\"dayOfWeek\": [";
        opening += "\"Tuesday\",";
        opening += "\"Wednesday\",";
        opening += "\"Thursday\",";
        opening += "\"Friday\",";
        opening += "\"Saturday\"";
        opening += "],";
        opening += "\"opens\": \"09:00\",";
        opening += "\"closes\": \"19:00\"";
        opening += "}";
        opening += "],";

        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(opening);
    }
}
```

In .aspx

```
<%:addressOpening.openingVal.Replace("quot;","\"") %>
```

Which then returns

```
&quot;openingHoursSpecification&quot;: [{&quot;@type&quot;: &quot;OpeningHoursSpecification&quot;,&quot;dayOfWeek&quot;: [&quot;Tuesday&quot;,&quot;Wednesday&quot;,&quot;Thursday&quot;,&quot;Friday&quot;,&quot;Saturday&quot;],&quot;opens&quot;: &quot;09:00&quot;,&quot;closes&quot;: &quot;19:00&quot;}],
```

I've tried the HtmlDecode Utility, also using Replace. Both of which do nothing.

Am I losing my mind?

Comment: The `<%: %>` syntax HTML encodes the content to the page, so it's working as intended.

Comment: Why are you HTML _decoding_? Your string value is does not contain any HTML encoded values.

Comment: Use `<%= %>` tag.

Comment: Html.Raw will bypass the encoding.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: @JonathonChase, interesting, `<%= %>` works.

Comment: Isnt this just JSON?  Why do a hundred concatenations when you can just serialize an object?